# Powershell - Stop if there is more than one match

Tags: windows, powershell

This is part of the code I created:

```
$NameBackup = "Backup"
$DestinationDrive = ""
Get-CimInstance win32_logicaldisk |
     ForEach-Object{
         if ($_.VolumeName -match "$NameBackup"){
             $DestinationDrive = "{0}{1}" -f $_.DeviceId,'\'
         }
     }
```

Basically it checks if there is any drive with the word "Backup" in the volume label and gets the letter of that drive.

Given this, I would like to create a code to stop the script and display an error message if there is more than one -match with the $NameBackup variable.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`-Filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-7.2#-filter) in this case, then check if the `.Count` property of the returned query is greater than 1, and if it is, use [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_throw?view=powershell-7.3) to halt your script. It may be also worth adding a new condition checking if `$cim` is populated.

```
$NameBackup = "Backup"
$cim = Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "VolumeName LIKE '%$NameBackup%'"
if($cim.Count -gt 1) {
    throw "More than one Volume Detected"
}
$DestinationDrive = $cim.DeviceID + '\'
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, excellent solution!

Thank you very much for your patience in explaining in detail, not only did I understand how this will help me in other scripts.

Comment: @TyroneHirt I'm glad the answer was helpful and you could learn something new :)